# Separating rows into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, rows

The date in which the status changes is being collected in one column, no matter if the status is sent or resent, etc. I would like the two dates to be separated into two columns. If anyone could help, that would be great!

Again, I'm using SSMS 2018.

What my table looks like:

```
+-------+--------+--------+------------+
| Code  | Name   | Status | StatusDate |
+-------+--------+--------+------------+     
|   221 | Kim    |  Resent|  2020-01-05|         
|   221 | Kim    |   Sent |  2020-01-01|             
+-------+--------+--------+---------+--+
```

What I want it to look like:

```
+-------+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+
| Code  | Name   | Type   | SentDate  | ResentDate| 
+-------+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+     
|   221 | Kim    |   Book | 2020-01-01| 2020-01-05|                   
+-------+--------+--------+---------+-------------+
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and where you got stuck. And why have you tagged CSS? Thats not relevant to a query?

Answer (score 1):

I would use conditional aggreagtion:

```
select code, name, type,
       max(case when status = 'Sent' then statusdate end) as sent_date,
       max(case when status = 'Resent' then statusdate end) as resent_date
from t
group by code, name, type;
```